# ProcessingJS not drawing images in 3D mode

Tags: javascript, processing

I am trying to draw an image to canvas using ProcessingJS. It works perfectly in 2D mode but not in 3D. The code looks the following:

```
PImage img;

void setup(){
    size(600, 400, OPENGL);
    strokeWeight(1);
    noFill();
    frameRate(60);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    img = loadImage("img.png");
}

void draw(){      

     image(img, 20, 20);

}
```

Any ideas what might cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of Processing.js that is older than 1.3.0, then this link might explain why it doesn't work:

https://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1511-image-doesnt-work-in-opengl-mode

Otherwise, you might try mapping your image as a texture on a polygon like in this example:

http://processing.org/learning/3d/texture1.html